# go mod tidy stuck with no error or timeout while resolving private dependency

Tags: go, go-modules

**Go Version**

```
go version go1.18.2 windows/amd64
```

**GO ENV**

```
go env
set GO111MODULE=on
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\XX\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\GOPATH\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/*
set GONOSUMDB=gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/*
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\GOPATH;C:\Users\XX\go
set GOPRIVATE=gitlabe2.ext.net.XX.com/*
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:\Program Files\Go
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Program Files\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.18.2
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\GIT\master\microservice\XX\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\makatiya\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build3671784636=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

while running the
`go mod tidy -v` for my project it seems to be stuck neither giving any error nor timeout
and this is happening only in windows(10) not on linux

**the o/p**

```
C:\GIT\master\microservice\XX>go install -v gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice/XX/common@v0.0.0-20230707094123-61deae19099f 
get "gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice/XX/common": found meta tag vcs.metaImport{Prefix:"gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice.git"} at //gitlab
e2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice/XX/common?go-get=1
get "gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice/XX/common": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
get "gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice": found meta tag vcs.metaImport{Prefix:"gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice.git"} at //gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice?go-get=1
get "gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice/XX": found meta tag vcs.metaImport{Prefix:"gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://gitlabe2.ext.net.x.com/XXX/microservice.git"} at //gitlabe2.ext.
net.x.com/XXX/microservice/XX?go-get=1
get "gitlabe2.ext.x.x.com/XXX/microservice/XX": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
```

**Solution Tried**

- Tried exporting different http proxies to no avail
- set GOSUMDB to both off and to sum.golang.or but did not help
- Checked for memory issues but everything was fine.
- Checked the access permissions

Comment: It's probably waiting for a subcommand like `git` to return. Use the `-x` to see all commands issued.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems like it may be related to it not being able to authenticate with the private source where it's attempting to pull the module from.

You should be able to get more info by using `go mod tidy -x` or `go mod tidy -x -v`. This should output more debugging info, which should inform you about which subcommand it's failing on.